# Laravel 8.12: syntax error, unexpected 'min' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto utilizando o Laravel 8.12 e PHP 7.3.21 e estou enfrentando o problema abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o conteúdo do arquivo head.blade.php

```
@stack('head_start')

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/icon-kit/dist/css/iconkit.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/ionicons/dist/css/ionicons.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="{{ assets( plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/weather-icons/css/weather-icons.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/c3/c3.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( plugins/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css) }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ assets( dist/css/theme.min.css) }}">
<script src="{{ assets( src/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js) }}"></script>

@stack('head_end')
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja o trecho dessa linha que você escreveu:

```
{{ assets( plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) }}
```

Isso é um erro de sintaxe. Você precisa de colocar o parâmetro de `assets` como `string`.

Assim:

```
{{ assets('plugins/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

No caso, coloque a aspas em todos os itens que estão em `assets`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Problema resolvido.